# From uniforms to Gaussians and the corner cases

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Denote by $\Phi$ the distribution function of the standard Gaussian distribution. Then $Z = \Phi^{-1}(U)$ has the standard Gaussian distribution.

The domain of $U$ is $[0, 1]$, and the domain of Gaussians is the real line $(-\infty, \infty)$. However, the domain of $Z$ seems to be the extended real line $[-\infty, \infty]$.

Where is the flaw in the above reasoning?

Comment: No flaw, just continue with $P(U=0)=P(U=1)=0$ hence $P(|Z|<\infty)=1$.

Comment: @Did, thank you for the quick response. I actually wanted to ask about domains, not supports. Maybe now there is a flaw. Is it correct to say that the domain of any distribution is the extended real line? It’s just that their supports are not.

Comment: What difference does this make when the random variables under consideration are almost surely finite?

Comment: @Did, I absolutely agree with you: no difference. I’m just trying to clarify to myself the definitions that I use; I want to be precise. If I’m eligible to plug in 0 or 1 into $\Phi^{-1}$, then the domain of Gaussians should be $[-\infty, \infty]$. Whether it is the case is my question.

Comment: And what I explained already twice is that the choice is yours, as long as you put no weight on $\pm\infty$.